# Share WebStorm (or any IntelliJ) configurations per repo?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've always used to ignore `.idea` directory, but, this makes sharing configuration uncomfortable (manual exports/imports). Also, sometimes, you could need to have `per-repo` configurations.

So, **how to do it?** Is there any official solutions? Plugin?

Comment: What exactly do you want to share?

Comment: Everything, from the `code style` to the `list of active plugins` and beyond.

Comment: List of active plug-ins is not stored in the project, it's IDE level configuration.

Comment: well, what can we share and how?

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839.

Comment: this is a good point, can you please attach it to an answer? It may will help other users too

Answer (score 0):

here is a good `.gitignore` with covers many Jetbrains ides: 
https://www.gitignore.io/api/phpstorm